# MuPAD equation solving

Tags: matlab

I have `x(t)` defined as:

```
x(t) = Symbol::subScript(x,0) + Rb*`&phi;`(t)
```

I want to write the derivative of `phi(t)` in terms of `x(t)`. When I try

```
diff(`&phi;`(t),t)
```

it doesn't substitute from the `x(t)` equation.

Comment: Could you maybe post the exact code you used with MuPAD ?

Comment: that was the exact code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note, that for MuPAD assignments only happens when you use `a:=1` and not with `a=1`.

So you should write

```
x(t) := Symbol::subScript(x,0) + Rb*`&phi;`(t)
```

instead. But then

```
diff(`&phi;`(t),t)
```

only gives \begin{align}
\frac{\partial}{\partial t} \phi(t)\end{align}

However, it works the other way around

```
`&phi;`(t) := 1/Rb*(x(t)-Symbol::subScript(x,0))
```

Then you can use

```
diff(`&phi;`(t),t)
```

to get
\begin{align}
\frac{\frac{\partial}{\partial t} x(t)}{Rb}
\end{align}